# How to differentiate users with accounts from guests in a ranking table?

Tags: hyperlinks, visual-cues

In a game, I have a table with the max points of the players.

Some of the users are registered and others are guests (anonymous). The difference is that the name of registered users has a link to visit the profile.

I want to make easy to know that some users are registered and others aren't, but people are asking: "Why some names are bold / underlined, etc"?

Is there any way to do this obvious?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just building on MFrank2012's answer here, but I'd be tempted to cut down on the number of characters and use the short word 'guest' (if it makes sense to do so) and would also make it more obvious that the other names are links with a (blue) color, or underline

[image]

Comment: good idea ,the term guest is pretty synonymous with someone who hasn't registered,so it would be hard to figure out what it means

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you go for a simple solution like this

**Nombre/Nick**

- Dificul 2-5 (unregistered)
- Dificul 3-5 (unregistered)
- Dificul 4-5 (unregistered)
- astroboy

Make the **unregistered** text have a link or a hover over so that people on hovering over it can find out what unregistered means.The registered users (Astroboy in this case) be will still be active links so that their profiles can be visited.